# travis-ci regex on travis_tag is not resolving

Tags: travis-ci

I have a segment of travis where it checks for the cassadra_version env variable.

`if [ ! -z ${CASSANDRA_VERSION} ]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

I would like for also to run only if there are no tags called deploy.

I have tried:
`if [ ! -z ${CASSANDRA_VERSION} ] && [ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" =~ '^((?!deploy).)*$' ]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

but it gives me a binary operator error

`if [ [! -z ${CASSANDRA_VERSION} ] && [ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" =~ '^((?!deploy).)*$' ]]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

also gives me an error

`if [ [! -z ${CASSANDRA_VERSION} ] && [ ${TRAVIS_TAG} =~ '^((?!deploy).)*$' ]]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

also.

then I also tried just having:
if [ ${TRAVIS_TAG} =~ '^((?!deploy).)*$' ]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

it also giving me the binary operator.

am i not doing the regex properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were not far, your main issue is that `~=` is not a universal test operator, but a `bash` specific one.
To use these `bash` advanced test operators, you have to use **double brackets**.

This will work:

`if [ ! -z ${CASSANDRA_VERSION} ] && [[ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" =~ ^((?!deploy).)*$ ]]; then ./setup-cassandra.sh; fi;`

Well, if your regexp is correct ;)

To know more about those improved operators: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: My fault!
**Bash** (and that's what's frustrating with it) is very sensible to whitespaces...
I tried to do a special effect in my answer to put the brackets in bold... But the spaces between the brackets and the text don't survive to a copy/paste...
I've edited my answer, now you should be able to copy that line.